# Django Delete CBV with confirmation pop-up and multiple success url

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my case, an instance Model can be delete from:

- a ListView inherited View
- a DetailView inherited View

By default, when a delete view is called:

- the `get` function calls 'confirm_delete' template. Instead I want a pop-up/modal to appear, and if `delete` is clicked in the modal will delete the object
- if the `delete` operation is on a ListView, after delete the user will remain on ListView and the ListView content will be updated
- if the `delete` operation is on a DetailView, after delete the user will be redirected to the ListView or another page(depending on other rules)

--

So I want to know how to do Ajax calls on delete, how to have conditional success urls in delete, based of where I am before the action.

Comment: You should use [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) for deleting an object. `ListView` and `DetailView` are called with **GET** request. When modifying your data you should always require **POST** request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the `DetailView` you can simply use a form as follows:

```
<form action="{% url "app:delete" object.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Clicking on the button will open a confirm dialog. If the users clicks `OK` the form will be submitted. This will delete the object and redirect to the same way the `confirm_delete` page would have redirected.

For the `ListView` can simply send a `POST` request to the `DeleteView` and on success reload the current page to update the `ListView`. How you send your AJAX request depends on whether you use any libraries, but with jQuery it could be done as follows:

```
$.ajax('{% url "app:delete" object.id %}', {
    method: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        window.location.reload();
    },
});
```

Note: don't forget to include the `csrf_token` for the AJAX request to work. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/) for more information.

Comment: Any reason why the first solution wouldn't work? I tried in chrome, I get the alert box, but when I confirm, it doesn't proceed, it just closes the alert box.

Comment: Never mind, my button type was 'button', it should have been 'submit'. It works perfectly fine, my mistake.